# Converting a gray gradient to grayscale in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, grayscale

I have a InDesign document and my printer needs my "grays" in grayscales. My document has some reds and also some CYMK grays. Is there a easy way to convert the grays to grayscales but keep the other colors correct?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of this is. Are there so many gradients that you avoid editing these by hand? You are not posting enough details to give a full picture, but there is probably no quick fix here.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the swatch to be 0% (C,M,Y); x% (K); OR edit the swatch to be 0,0,0,100% and then set the item to a percentage tint; OR set the items to "Black" and set a percentage tint.

If you leave them assigned to a swatch instead of "standard black," you can easily re-edit the color value without much effort nor effect on other elements.

If you use the swatch for other things you will need to re-assign a new swatch to those items.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot but what about my gray gradients? How can I "recreate" them to be grayscale and not containing any other C M Y? Thanks.

Comment: change the color